# The specified database connection is not defined: default for Drupal drush

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have the following configurations for my Drupal site:

`sites/mysite/settings.local.php`

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'mydb',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

and for drush, I have :
`drush/sites/local.site.yml`

```
mysite:
  root: /Users/me/Desktop/Work/Projects/mysite/docroot
  uri: mysite.local
```

Now when I run  `drush @local.mysite cr` , I am getting:

```
The specified database connection is not defined: default
```

If I run `drush @local.mysite status`, I get:

```
Drupal version : 9.5.9
Site URI       : http://mysite.local
PHP binary     : /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.19/bin/php
PHP config     : /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php.ini
PHP OS         : Darwin
Drush script   : /usr/local/bin/drush
Drush version  : 10.6.1
Drush temp     : /tmp
Drush configs  : /Users/me/Desktop/Work/Projects/mysite/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
Drupal root    : /Users/me/Desktop/Work/Projects/mysite/docroot
Site path      : sites/default
```

From this error, I assume that Drush is using the default settings and not the one specified for my site. But I have added the same database configurations to the default settings, which is not working. Also, I have copied the `settings.local.php`, but it also gives me the same error. I am new to Drupal, and it is an existing codebase that I am working on. It would be very helpful if someone could help me use Drush correctly so I can set up my local development environment.

I have tried to connect to database from the command line, and it is working and also I am able to access the database from PHPMyAdmin

Comment: This helped me. https://www.techpond.in/drush-specified-database-connection-not-defined-default

Answer (score 0):

Your `sites/mysite/settings.local.php` should probably be named `sites/mysite/settings.php`. Unless you already have a settings.php including your settings.local.php.

I also see you have it in a `mysite` folder. Are you settings up a multisite drupal installation? Otherwise just put it in the `default` folder.

Drupal by default loads `settings.php` for a sites settings. This file than can optionally include a `settings.local.php`.
See The [source for where it specifically does it](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.1.x/sites/default/default.settings.php?ref_type=heads#L860).
You would only generally have this settings.local.php file for settings overrides specifically for the current machine and would usually not commit this to a repository

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue while executing a drush command. The reason behind my error was a missing directory alias in sites.php file. For ex: I had a site with "example.local.com" and I had created a site folder with the name "example". I had to add a directory alias in sites.php file to fix the issue.

```
$sites['example.local.com'] = 'example';
```

Hope this helps someone!!

Refer: https://www.techpond.in/drush-specified-database-connection-not-defined-default